# I want to catch the STDERR and STDOUT of Background running script

Tags: shell-script, stdout, stderr

I have to run a script background and also i have to catch the STDERR and STDOUT . i'm using the below line .

```
test.sh & >> log_file 2>&1
```

But un fortunately nothing is getting written to log_file

Please help me here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the position of the background `&` character:

```
test.sh >> log_file 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , i completely ignored the position . Now it works

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
( echo stdout; echo >&2 stderr )& >> log 2>&1;
sleep 0.1; echo LOG:; cat log
```

and shows that both stdout and stderr get to the log.

The error must be somewhere in your `test.sh`.